# Java Error when using Scanner, "no suitable constructor found for Scanner"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am using Scanner and BufferedReader objects to read text input from a url, and am getting this compile time error: no suitable constructor found for Scanner.

any suggestions would be appreciated, here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.*;
public class Processor 
{

public void start(){
  readInput();
  sort();
  writeOutput();
}
public void readInput()
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
URL file = new URL("http://file.txt");
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.openStream()));
Customer[] customerList = new Customer[40000];

scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Use IDE like eclipse, which can help you in solving problem like these. It will also gives you option for you to select.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scanner class doesnt have a default constructor, 
See this doc 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

For example, this code allows a user to read a number from System.in:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int i = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 2):

Scanner requires a parameter in its constructor.  A File or some form of InputStream usually.  Otherwise how does scan.nextLine() know what it's scanning?

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner();
```

Of [these constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor_summary), which one accepts 0 arguments?